# Apache server, two cache control max-age values

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

Im trying to set up cache control for a site running on Ubuntu 16.04 using an Apache server. This is the .htaccess file for the site:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

When checking the headers in Chrome dev tools for an image, I see two max-age values:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=60, public, max-age=31536000
Content-Type:image/jpeg
```

It seems like the first value is overriding the second value because no resources on my site are being cached for more than a minute. Where is the first value of 60 being defined?

Comment: Not in the config you've shown us.

Comment: Yes. So where else could it be? Ive been searching through config files for two hours with no luck.

Comment: generated by backend?

Comment: That was it. A package I had pulled in to resize images was setting a cache control header. Thank you!